# Prove that odd numbers of the form 6n + 1 cannot be represented as the difference of primes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have tried to prove it by induction but no success. Then tied to prove it by contradiction and also no progress. Can you please give me some direction on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What values of $n$ should we be checking here? Because we have $6(0)+1 = 3-2$

Comment: $6n+1$ is an odd number, can only be difference between an odd and an even number. There is only one even prime number which is $2$. But then the other prime will be $6n+3$ which is divisible by $3$. Besides $n=0$, $6n+3$ is never a prime.

Comment: @rezha!  You blew my cover!

Answer (score 2):

For a difference to be odd, the numbers you subtract must be one even and one odd.  So you need to include an even prime in that subtraction.  That even prime would then have to be ... .

Once you figure that out, you should then infer that in order to get a difference of $6n+1$, the other number in the subtraction must be composite, provided $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Any integer $m$ can be written as $6n-3=3(2n-1),6n-2=2(3n-1),6n-1,6n,6n+1,6n+2=2(3n+1)$

So, all the primes are of the form

$$2=6\cdot0+2,3=3(2\cdot-1),6n+1,6n-1$$  where $n$ is any integer

Now find the possible differences among them

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted - *twice*? This makes perfect sense to me, and given the actual simplicity of the problem, I find it rather generous of this user to provide a hint with a thorough by-case explanation. +1

Comment: Because there is a simpler method, maybe?  (No I did not down-vote, just trying to diagnose.)

Comment: @MrPie, Thanks for your appreciation . Such uncanny behavior is not new to me!